# Using advanced constructors to convert array to armadillo vec

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to convert an object of type ODE_vector to an armadillo vec such that the new object will inherit the linear algebraic functionality of the armadillo library.  As a simple example of the problem I am having this is a demonstration using a C++ array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main() {

double b1 = 0.2;
double b2 = 0.1;
const double state[2] = {b1, b2};

rowvec B(&state[0], 2);
cout << B << endl;

mat A(2,2); A.fill(0.2); A.diag().ones();
cout << A << endl;

cout << B(0) * A(0,0) << endl;    // x

return 0;

}
```

The data contained in b1 and b2 is saved in the elements of B so that running this script returns the following:

```
   0.2000
   0.1000

   1.0000   0.2000
   0.2000   1.0000

0.2
```

HOWEVER, if I replace line x above with

```
cout << B * A << endl;
```

I get errors suggesting B has not inherited the standard armadillo linear algebra functionality:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable untitled
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `void arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/wrapper_blas.hpp:36: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemv_'
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `void arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const*, char const*, int const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/wrapper_blas.hpp:71: undefined reference to `wrapper_dgemm_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'untitled' failed
make[3]: *** [untitled] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'untitled' failed
make: *** [untitled] Error 2
```

Can anyone explain how to properly use the advanced constructors ([arma documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat)) to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the right format in the multiplication. Type B is a 2x1 and A is 2x2. Change to

```
mat B(&state[0], 1,2);
```

or

```
rowvec B(&state[0], 2);
```

Comment: I wish it were that simple!!  I've tried various combinations of armadillo classes but that doesn't solve the problem.  I'll edit the question to avoid confusion and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure that you have BLAS enabled in your build? For me the two 
 alternatives of line 'x' above worked fine.

Comment: You're right!  it wasn't properly linked, it was a CMake issue...  If anyone else if having similar problems check out this link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205823019-Errors-compiling-code-with-armadillo    THANKS FOR THE HELP!!